# Can any non-piecewise rectangular function be written as a non-piecewise polar function?

Tags: polar-coordinates

Can any non-piecewise rectangular function $y=f(x)$ be written as a non-piecewise polar function $r=g(θ)$?

I tried exploring a few examples—such as converting $y=\sin x$ into polar form—but most of these are too difficult for me as they involve big-O notation.

I am just looking for a *yes* or *no* and a brief explanation or example that shows why or how the answer is *yes* or *no*.

Comment: "Piecewise" isn't really a meaningful term. All functions are just relations between a domain and co-domain. The way we write them down is sort of human-centric. Sine is just a label for a particular function; you might as well just define some rectangle function and call it $f(x)=\operatorname{Rect}(x)$.

Comment: Although to be clear, phrases like "piecewise linear" are meaningful, since they have precise definitions that start with "there exists a partition $P$ such that... ."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Consider $f(x) = x$. In polar form, this has the equation $\theta = \pi/4$. There's no way to write this in the form of a polar function $r = g(\theta)$.